# Filter dataframe on occurrence of same values across columns AND at column end

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:19,
  Area_l = c(1,2,0,0,0,2,3,1,2,0,0,0,0,3,4,0,0,0,0),
  Area_r = c(3,2,2,0,0,2,3,1,0,0,0,1,3,3,4,3,0,0,0)
)
```

I need to filter the dataframe in such a way that all rows are omitted that fulfill two conditions:

(i): `Area_l` and `Area_r` are `0`

(ii): the paired `0`values in `Area_l` and `Area_r` are the **last** values in the columns.

I really have no clue how to implement these two conditions using `dplyr`. The **desired result** is this:

```
df
   id Area_l Area_r
1   1      1      3
2   2      2      2
3   3      0      2
4   4      0      0
5   5      0      0
6   6      2      2
7   7      3      3
8   8      1      1
9   9      2      0
10 10      0      0
11 11      0      0
12 12      0      1
13 13      0      3
14 14      3      3
15 15      4      4
16 16      0      3
```

Any help?

Comment: The ones with `id` 17:19 in `df`. Or put differently, there are no more occurrences of values `!= 0` as one moves downward in the columns, only `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `rle`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(!if_all(starts_with("Area"), ~ .x == 0 & 
     inverse.rle(within.list(rle(.x == 0), values[-length(values)] <- FALSE))))
```

-output

```
    id Area_l Area_r
1   1      1      3
2   2      2      2
3   3      0      2
4   4      0      0
5   5      0      0
6   6      2      2
7   7      3      3
8   8      1      1
9   9      2      0
10 10      0      0
11 11      0      0
12 12      0      1
13 13      0      3
14 14      3      3
15 15      4      4
16 16      0      3
```

---

Or another option is

```
df %>%
   filter(if_any(starts_with("Area"), 
        ~ row_number() <= max(row_number() * (.x != 0))))
```

---

Or another option is `revcumsum` from `spatstat.utils`

```
library(spatstat.utils)
df %>% 
    filter(!if_all(starts_with("Area"), ~ revcumsum(.x != 0) <1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the order of the dataframe, filter with a `cumany` condition, then reverse it back.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  map_df(rev) %>% 
  filter(cumany(Area_l + Area_r != 0)) %>% 
  map_df(rev)
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 16 x 3
      id Area_l Area_r
   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1      1      3
 2     2      2      2
 3     3      0      2
 4     4      0      0
 5     5      0      0
 6     6      2      2
 7     7      3      3
 8     8      1      1
 9     9      2      0
10    10      0      0
11    11      0      0
12    12      0      1
13    13      0      3
14    14      3      3
15    15      4      4
16    16      0      3
```

Comment: Very neat solution.

Comment: Nice! What exactly does `cumany` do?

Comment: `cumany` is the cumulative version of `any`. In this case, it sets cases to `FALSE` until the condition is met for the first time, i.e. here when `Area_l + Area_r == 0`, and sets to `TRUE` every subsequent value. So combined with filter (which only keeps `TRUE` values), it removes every rows before the first `TRUE`.